# NodeJS passing results form HTTPS request to the view

Tags: node.js, view, https, routes

I am making an HTTPS request to an API (wrike.com) and everythings working except I'm struggling to pass the result to my view in order to display in the frontend.

This is the function code:

```
module.exports.getWrikeFolder = function(user, callback) {
User.findOne({email: user}, function(err, doc){
if(err) throw err;
var accessToken = doc.wrikeaccess;
console.log(accessToken);

var data = querystring.stringify({
  "descendants": true,
  "project": false
});

var options = {
  host: 'www.wrike.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/v3/folders/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken
  }
}

var folders = [];

var request = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    folders.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    folders = Buffer.concat(folders).toString();
    console.log(folders);
  });

});

request.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

request.write(data);
request.end(err, folders);
});
}
```

And this is the code for the route:

```
router.get('/dmd', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
wrike.getWrikeFolder(user, function(err, folders) {
    //if(err) throw err;
    res.render('dmd-codes', {
        title: 'DMD Codes',
        nav: 'Admin',
        folders: folders
    });
  });
});
```

I know the function works as the `console.log(folders);` line shows the expected result in the console. What am I missing to get the result into the route.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you never execute your `callback` in the module that does the http request to the API, which means the `res.render()` wouldn't execute. Try adding the execution of `callback` inside of `getWrikeFolder()`:

```
module.exports.getWrikeFolder = function(user, callback) {
  User.findOne({email: user}, function(err, doc){
    // if(err) throw err; // NOOOO! Use callbacks ;)
    if (err) return callback(err);

    // ... (your code)

    var request = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        folders.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', function() {
        folders = Buffer.concat(folders).toString();
        console.log(folders);

        // make sure to execute callback!
        callback(null, folders);

      });

    });

    request.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
      // don't forget to use the callback!!
      return callback( new Error('problem with request: ' + e.message) );
    });

    request.write(data);
    request.end(err, folders);
  });
}
```

Comment: no problem! Don't forget those callbacks in Node!! Remember that almost everything is asynchronous.

Comment: Hi Jakerella, this isn't passing the variable as an array. I tried taking `toString()` away from the function but this doesn't do it either. Would you be able to tell me how to turn this into an array so I can do a for loop within my view to display the data in an ordered away? Thanks again for any help you can give.

Comment: HTTP only ever returns strings, period. On the client side, if you have a proper JSON array then you can try calling `JSON.parse()` on the returned value in the response (on the client side).